# selenium After clicking on a link pointing to a new tab, he does not see the buttons and fields

Tags: java, selenium, tabs, new-operator

My problem is as follows:
I click on the link that opens a new tab in the browser, I switch to this tab and I want to click on the field to enter text.
Unfortunately it returns me:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='nameFields']"}
```

I have tried various ways to even close the first tab (tabs.get(0)).

```
    public exampleMethod() {
        ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));
        System.out.println("tab 0: " + driver.getTitle());
        driver.close();
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
        System.out.println("tab 1: " + driver.getTitle());
        //driver.navigate().refresh();
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nameInput']")).sendKeys("qwerty");
        nameInput.sendKeys("qwerty");
        submit.click();
        return this;
    }
```

```
There is no problem with listing the page titles.
```

Answer (score 0):

Bbefore nameInput.sendKeys("qwerty"), use wait by following code

```
WebElement we = new WebDriverWait(driver, 25).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='nameInput']")));
```